# C# Decompress MP3 to Text

Tags: c#, mp3, binary-data, compression

I am building a tool that extracts data from binary database files. I have it working on fixed width uncompressed data, but the next file I tried is using a compression method.

According to TRiD (http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) the file is a 100% match to MP3, for what it is worth, here is the first few bytes of the file:

```
FF FF AD 00 C0 7E AA 00 21 C0 AD 00 AE 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 86 00 
00 52 81 00 00 00 00 00 00 CC 01 00 00 42 54 47 42 91 00 00 00 57 01 00 40 
32 00 30 00 34 12 EE 1F 00 00 01 00 00 02 01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 54 1C 73 5A 00 00 49 02 FF 00 
02 00 AF 89 00 00 00 00 00 00 6B 04 00 00 56 1C 73 5A B3 06 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

My application normally takes a block of binary data, which can be from anywhere in the file, and saves it to a small file that is easy to do quick manipulations of till the data all lines up.

If I want to do that with a compressed file, do I need to decompress the entire file first, then save only a portion, or can I tell it to grab the first 30k of the file, decompress what it finds and write that out to a file? I know there will be lot's of extra unicode / control chars, but as long as the string values are printable, I will figure out the rest.

```
public static FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"DB.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
public static FileStream shortFile = null;
int limit = 30000;

public MainWindow()
{
    byte[] block = new byte[limit];

    using (FileStream fs = File.Create("tempfile.dat"))
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.Read(block, 0, limit);

        fs.Write(block, 0, block.Length);

    }

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Edit: Adding ID info for sample file http://64.72.211.216/ZIPCODE.dat

```
TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.24 - (C) 2003-16 By M.Pontello
Definitions found:  10674
Analyzing...

Collecting data from file: ZIPCODE.dat
100.0% (.MP3) MP3 audio (1000/1)
         Mime type  : audio/mpeg3
       Definition   : audio-mp3.trid.xml
         Files      : 34
       Author       : Marco Pontello
         E-Mail     : marcopon@gmail.com
         Home Page  : http://mark0.net
```

Comment: I can't possibly see how this is a good idea. Arbitrarily editing MP3 frames by text? Hmmm. Out of interest, what's your intended usage scenario?

Comment: The MP3 Compression format is being applied to text that is stored in the database.

Comment: I'm more confused than ever. MP3 is a ***lossy*** format for ***audio*** tailored specifically to the intricacies of the human ear. You'll never round-trip text via MP3... it just won't work.

Comment: I.e. The PCM data that is fed into an MP3 compressor is substantially different from the PCM data that is emitted from the MP3 decompressor. It might sound the same to the human ear, but the similarity stops there.

Comment: Here is a sample http://64.72.211.216/ZIPCODE.dat

Comment: That's not an MP3 file. You've been led astray by a bad identification. If it were truely mp3, you could rename it to `coolmusic.mp3` and expect no errors when playing it back in an audio player. It's a more realistic test than this `TRiD` that you are using. Does this happen? What are you really trying to do here? Decode files of unknown provenance? Where does this data really come from and why don't you know what it is?

Comment: I know it isn't really an MP3 music file, but there is a compression format used by MP3 that could be used in other ways right? My first tool extracts data from the 20+ year old C-Tree Plus database, after it was working I thought I would look at their new database format to see what my tool could do. In my work I am connecting to a WIDE array of databases, (Sybase, Mysql, C-TreeACE, C-Tree Plus, ElevateDB, Cache, MSSQL, with the list still growing). I always know what the origin of the file is, but I am looking for how to decode the string values, then I can figure out the structure later.

Comment: Looks like it was probably zlib compression, I will post a new question and ask accordingly. https://docs.faircom.com/doc/v10ace/55874.htm

Comment: "there is a compression format used by MP3 that could be used in other ways right?" Wrong. MP3 uses psychoacoustic modelling to make savings that only make sense in terms of audio. It's completely inappropriate for any other kind compression task. "Inappropriate" as in "won't work at all".

Comment: It doesn't look like an MP3, not like ZIP either. It's block-oriented, with disk-block sized blocks (512bytes). I don't know what it is, but that excludes a lot of well known file types.